# Power BI sort by groups even if no value

Tags: powerbi

I'm working with aged invoices and payments in power BI. I have a bar chart that groups payments into 0-30, 30-60, 60-90, > 90 based on how long it has been since the invoice they are associated with was created. I am only interested in showing this information for payments that were received during the last 7 days. I have an age of payment sort order column in my data set that is calculated as follows:

```
AgeOfPaymentSortOrder = IF(Payment[AgeOfPayment (groups)] = "0-30", 1, IF(Payment[AgeOfPayment (groups)] = "30-60", 2, IF(Payment[AgeOfPayment (groups)] = "60-90", 3, 4)))
```

I'm using this sort order to ensure that the bars are ordered as 0-30, 30-60, 60-90, >90. However, I don't have any payments that are 60-90 days old. I have selected 'show items without data' so I can see 60-90 on my bar chart, but now the sort order won't work.

Any ideas would be great please!

Cheers,

Comment: Create a separate table for Age groups with the same ids as your sort order. Connect this table to your payments table on the AgeOfPaymentSortOrder, and use Age group sortable by id in your charts.